# Can SQL AG be used across 2 sites over the internet to create replica readonly db on remote server?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2019

I have SQLSVR1 having multiple dbs located in Scotland.

One of these dbs is used in an ETL process running on SQLSVR2 located in a remote data center located in London via linked server.

The ETL process takes long time to run the queries using linked server, due to latency.

Both data centers are on separate network and don't have any trust between the AD.

Can SQL AG be used to create a realtime read-only AG replica in async mode betwrrn SQLSVR1 and SQLSVR2? Or do I need to use distributed AG in this scenario?

Comment: "*The ETL process takes long time to run the queries using linked server*" - I'm always weary when I hear slow and Linked Server. I'd look into the execution plans of your queries using the Linked Server, and if you see `Remote Scan` (as opposed to `Remote Query`) as the operator, then your issue isn't latency related, rather your execution plans aren't optimal, and is pulling all of the data of the entire Table across the Linked Server locally first to then filter it down to the rows you care about before processing the rest of the query and then making the changes on the remote server.

Comment: The etl processes large data (about million rows) from handful of tables. I cannot change the etl but have the ability to configure AG or another solution like replication.

Comment: That's fine, I'm not necessarily suggesting you change your ETL process. There's alternative ways to fix the problem, even while still using Linked Servers, but you should understand the problem first (which I would bet my money on is `Remote Scans` not a latency issue).

Comment: Can SQL AG be used to create a realtime read-only AG replica in async mode across 2 data centers that don't share an AD or cluster?

Comment: AGs are not guaranteed to be real time in any sense of the meaning.

Comment: But do they have the ability to function across cluster and internet?

Comment: DAG, not AG fits best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One of these dbs is used in an ETL process running on SQLSVR2 located in a remote data center located in London via linked server.

> Can SQL AG be used to create a realtime read-only AG replica in async mode betwrrn SQLSVR1 and SQLSVR2? Or do I need to use distributed AG in this scenario?

So long as you meet the requirements for an AG, it doesn't care what your topology looks like (it has no idea what the internet vs intranet vs whatever else is). If you can check all the boxes, it'll technically work. Whether or not it works well is a completely different question. Whether or not to use a distributed AG depends on your configuration.